# Eclipse plugin update to downloaded user

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, update-site

I created a eclipse plugin project. I am new to this & i wanted to know after installing this project by user through update site - how can i make a change so the user get the update for the existing plugin.

Comment: Update the feature and plugin version numbers to a higher number.

Answer (score 0):

to add the plugin follow these steps

Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.

Click Add, in the top-right corner.

In the Add Repository add the link
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can add ".qualifier" as part of the plugins and features version. Every time you build p2repository with your feature ".qualifier" is replaced by timestamp. Yo can also configure format of this time stamp if you want.